# load CoreData failed in release version

Tags: ios, core-data, optimization, release

My app have a `Trip` entity which has a **to-many** relationship to `Spot` entity, and I need to load trip and its spot list in the background thread. It works fine in debug version, but in release version, the spot list is empty! So I dug a little and found, it cannot work in release version unless I set the compiler optimization level to `-O0`. I think it may be a bug of the compiler.

Is there any suggestion to make it work for higher optimization level, or I have to release a non-optimized app? Thanks!

Here is the code:

Main thread

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(calcRoute:) withObject:self.trip.objectID];
```

Background thread

```
- (void)calcRoute:(NSManagedObjectID *)tripId
{
    //get trip entity
    CoreDataHelper * helper = nil;  //responsible for init model, persistentStore and context
    TripEntity * t = nil;
    helper = [[CoreDataHelper alloc] initWithAnother:mainThreadHelper];  //only take the resource name and storeURL
    t = (TripEntity *)[helper.context objectWithID:tripId];   //retrieve trip
    if (0 == t.spotList.count) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(drawRouteFailed) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:FALSE];
        return;   //I got here!
    }
//...
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your multithreading code is incorrect. It might be working in the debug version simply because of timing. How are you doing your multithreading? (showing code would help)

Comment: Well, I pass the trip objectID to background thread, and re-create the CoreData model, context and persistantStore in that thread, then retrieve the trip entity by objectID. Since I only read the CoreData, there is no sync issue.

Comment: "Since I only read the CoreData, there is no sync issue." that is not necessarily true. Yeah, it won't crash, but it doesn't mean that the data will be in sync. You should look into parent/child contexts and read the [concurrency guide for Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html). Hard to know if that is the problem, but it seems likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. The reason is: I '*used*' the main thread trip entity. Here is the  actual code:

```
- (void)calcRoute:(NSManagedObjectID *)tripId
{
    //get trip entity
    CoreDataHelper * helper = nil;  //responsible for init model, persistentStore and context
    TripEntity * t = nil;
    if (self.backgroundDrow) {  //sometimes I don't need background drawing
        helper = [[CoreDataHelper alloc] initWithAnother:mainThreadHelper];  //only take the resource name and storeURL
        t = (TripEntity *)[helper.context objectWithID:tripId];   //retrieve trip
    } else
        t = self.mainThreadTrip;         //HERE is the problem!!!
    if (0 == t.spotList.count) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(drawRouteFailed) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:FALSE];
        return;   //I got here!
    }
    //...
}
```

After I comment `t = self.mainThreadTrip;`, the background loading becomes OK!

But I still don't get the point! Would someone tell me the real reason? Thanks a lot!